# Django/Graphene mutations doesn't apply

Tags: python, django, graphene-python

I am currently creating a GraphQL interface for my Django app, using Python-Graphene. While queries works great, mutations - not quite.

The model for `Ingredient`:

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False)
    needs_refill = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField('created', auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField('modified', auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Ingredient, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Here's the schema code (full code here: https://ctrlv.it/id/107369/1044410281):

```
class IngredientType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Ingredient

...

class CreateIngredient(Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        name = String()

    ok = Boolean()
    ingredient = Field(IngredientType)

    def mutate(self, info, name):
        ingredient = IngredientType(name=name)
        ok = True
        return CreateIngredient(ingredient=ingredient, ok=ok)


class MyMutations(ObjectType):
    create_ingredient = CreateIngredient.Field()


schema = Schema(query=Query, mutation=MyMutations)
```

and my mutation:

```
mutation {
  createIngredient(name:"Test") {
    ingredient {
      name
    }
    ok
  }
}
```

Running it returns proper object and `ok` is `True`, but no data is pushed to the database. What should I do? What did I miss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Close...inside your `mutate` method you need to save your ingredient as an instance of `Ingredient` (not `IngredientType`) and then use that to create your `IngredientType` object.  Also, you should declare `mutate` as `@staticmethod`.  Something like:

```
    @staticmethod
    def mutate(root, info, name):
        ingredient = Ingredient.objects.create(name=name)
        ok = True
        return CreateIngredient(ingredient=ingredient, ok=ok)
```

Comment: Works great, thanks! Can you elaborate, why should I use the `@classmethod`?

Comment: Actually, the docs show that you should use a `@staticmethod` instead, which would mean that the `cls` is taken out of the method signature.  http://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/types/mutations/ .   I'll update my answer.

Comment: And if turns out that `staticmethod` does not work, let me know, I will change the answer back.

Comment: Sorry for the late feedback, Mark. Yeah, `@staticmethod` works well, so thanks again!